# SQL: How to SUM the same value on two different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

Lets say I have the following table which records who has invested in a list of companies.

```
Table: corporate_investments

company investor investment date
--------------------------------
CorpA    Alice     10       12/1
CorpB    Bob       20       12/2
CorpB    Sally     20       12/3 
CorpC    Cathy     30       12/4
CorpC    Alice     40       12/5
CorpC    Bob       10       12/6
CorpC    Bob       20       12/7
```

How would I run a query that returns each company, their total investments by Bob(who is a VIP) and the total invested in that company?

I tried

```
SELECT company,SUM(investment) as total investment
FROM corporate_investments
GROUP BY company
```

which succeeds in finding the total amount invested.

```
company    total_investment
---------------------------
CorpA           10
CorpB           40
CorpC          100
```

Now i want to add Bob's total amount for each company. I need something like a clause inside the SUM() function itself but am puzzled how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT company, SUM(investment) as total,
       sum(case when investor = 'Bob' then investment else 0 end) as BobTotal
FROM corporate_investments
GROUP BY company;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a rolling total for each investor using `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT company, investor, SUM(investment) AS total
FROM corporate_investments
GROUP BY company, investor WITH ROLLUP
```

Which would yield something like this:

```
CorpA    Alice     10
CorpA    NULL      10
CorpB    Bob       20
CorpB    Sally     20
CorpB    NULL      40
CorpC    Alice     40
CorpC    Bob       30
CorpC    Cathy     30
CorpC    NULL     100
```

Comment: That is useful, but not what I needed for the output. I'll save this to remember it later.